# Rally Query in the SDK 1 vs Store in the SDK 2

Tags: javascript, rally

I am trying to create an exportable to CSV grid app for Rally to show dependencies. but i am not getting the results i would expected for the SDK 2 using a store. I found a legacy SDK 1 app that is returning what i am looking for.

I not sure what i need to do the get the predecessors to show. all i am getting is a count from the store in the data object. I have been through the docs a bunch of times and i am stuck.

```js
 var dependencydata = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'hierarchicalrequirement',
    autoLoad: true,
    
       listeners: {
        load: function(dependencydata, data, success) {
            //process data
            console.log("Woot Data !",dependencydata, data, success);
           this.loadgrid(dependencydata);
        },
        scope: this
    },
    fetch: ['Rank','FormattedID','Name','Predecessors','Successors','Project','ScheduleState']
});//end Store
```

The Result is

data

FormatId 12345

Blah

Predecessor

Count 2

What I need is

data

FormatId 12345

Blah

Predecessor

```
   object 

   Array

    FormatId 45637
```

In SDK 1 it would have been done like this I guess

```js
var queryConfig = {
                    type : 'hierarchicalrequirement',
                    key  : 'stories',
                    fetch: 'Rank,FormattedID,Name,Predecessors,Successors,Project,ScheduleState',
                    query: '(Release.Name = "' + relDropdown.getSelectedName() + '")',
                    order: 'Rank'
                };
                rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showUserStoriesTable);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v2.0 of WSAPI which is used by SDK 2 does not allow hydrating collections in one request like v1.0 did.

Luckily, there's a guide in the docs dealing with this exact topic:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2

Your case is slightly more complicated since you'll need to load 2 collections for each story (Predecessors and Successors)

So something like this should work:

```
//keep track of all the pending collection loads
var promises = [];

Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'UserStory',
    fetch: ['Rank','FormattedID','Name','Predecessors','Successors','Project','ScheduleState'],
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records) {              
           _.each(records, function(story) {
               //create the stores to load the collections
               story.predecessorStore = story.getCollection('Predecessors');
               story.successorStore = story.getCollection('Successors');

               //load the stores and keep track of the load operations
               promises.push(predecessorStore.load({fetch: ['FormattedID']}));
               promises.push(successorStore.load({fetch: ['FormattedID']}));
           });

           //wait for all promises to finish
           Deft.Promise.all(promises).then({
               success: function() {
                   //all data loaded.
                   console.log(records[0].predecessorStore.getRange());
                   console.log(records[0].successorStore.getRange());
               }
           });
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this will generate a ton of requests, so it is best to limit the total number of stories in the root store through filters.

Comment: Thank you I will try this a little later to night. Guess I shouldn't try to pull the entire collection of stories from the top of the tree 36000 + stories :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help I gave been able to get this to work with above code. Now I am struggling with passing this into grid. I would need to I guess would need to splice records[0] with records[0].predecessor to show in one line. on the grid.

Comment: You'll need to use a custom column definition with a renderer function.  So pass something like this to your columnCfgs in the grid:

{ dataIndex: 'Successors', text: 'Dependencies', renderer: function(value, metaData, record) { //use record.predecessorStore and record.successorStore to return the html you'd like to display in the cell}}